# how to modify an in includegraphic image in latex

Tags: graphics

I include a PNG picture using the `\includegraphics` command and it looks like this:

[image]

Would it be possible to modify it in LaTeX by including a legend and tick markers on the axis as well? Or a text box say next to a given plot?

Comment: I think answers to [Drawing on an image with TiKZ](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9559/drawing-on-an-image-with-tikz) will help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A rather brute force way of doing it in latex would be to use the tikz package, where you could do:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[anchor=south west] {\includegraphics[]{your_graphic.png}};
    \node at (0,0) {$0$};
    \draw (0,0) grid (10,10);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

this way you could draw and write stuff on the image. The problem is you have to figure out the coordinates for the different points for which the grid may help.

The more easy solution would probably be to use a graphics program like Inkscape which would allow you to write text and add lines using the mouse. Inkscape also supports multiple exports one of which is eps and eps+latex which gives you latex typeset text.

Hope this helps